# Chrome can only access google if I change the network

Tags: networking, google-chrome

I connect to 3 public WiFi over the day. 
When I change the network, IE works just fine but Chrome can only access Google. For all other pages I get: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

**Still working** with Chrome

https://www.youtube.com/

https://www.google.com/

https://www.google.com/maps

**Not working** from Chrome only few examples:

https://en.wikipedia.org/

https://gmail.com/

https://translate.google.com/

Running with *--enable-logging --v=1* I get

```
 Failed to connect to MCS endpoint with error -102
```

After restarting the computer all works fine.

Comment: What about mail.google.com? I have a specific thought.  Asking for a specific reason.

Comment: I played too much with it, now I can not access anything at all. But the problem exists for weeks, and I will check next time

Comment: Have you verified Chrome/IE are using the same proxy settings

Comment: Yes, none of them are using proxy. And I have 3 different instalations of chrome including Canary. I signed out, created other user. No resolution yet (except windows restart).

Comment: And restarting chrome doesn't help? What if you disable/reenable the network interface or disconnect/reconnect wifi? Or maybe you could do `ipconfig /release` followed by `ipconfig /renew`

Comment: I did not tried your suggestion for "ipconfig /release followed by ipconfig /renew" all other methods except Windows restart have no result. Including disabling network